# How to insert values in an entity with one to many relation on model creating with EF Core 3?

Tags: database-design, entity-framework-core

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Publisher>().HasData(
                new Publisher { Id = 1, Name = "Ciela" },
                new Publisher { Id = 2, Name = "Knigomania" },
                new Publisher { Id = 3, Name = "Bard" },
                new Publisher { Id = 4, Name = "Labyrinth" },
                new Publisher { Id = 5, Name = "Emgont" },
                new Publisher { Id = 6, Name = "Bloomsbury" }
                );

    modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasData(
                new Book
                {
                    BookId = 1,
                    Title = "book",
                    Author = "a",
                    Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    Quantity = 1,
                    Price = 5,
                    Publisher = Publishers.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Name.Equals("Bard"))
                });
}
```

I work with EF Core 3 and .NET Framework 4.7.2

This is my `ApplicationDbContext` file and I'm trying to insert values into the table when the database is being crated. Whenever I run this code I end up with the following error alert:

> An attempt was made to use the model while it was being created. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnModelCreating in any way that makes use of the model that is being created.

My question is: how do I resolve this issue so that the book is referenced to the according publisher? I was expecting EF Core 3 to deal with it, but apparently it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't using **PublisherId** !?
try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Publisher>().HasData(
            new Publisher { Id = 1, Name = "Ciela" },
            new Publisher { Id = 2, Name = "Knigomania" },
            new Publisher { Id = 3, Name = "Bard" },
            new Publisher { Id = 4, Name = "Labyrinth" },
            new Publisher { Id = 5, Name = "Emgont" },
            new Publisher { Id = 6, Name = "Bloomsbury" }
            );

modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasData(
            new Book
            {
                BookId = 1,
                Title = "book",
                Author = "a",
                Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Quantity = 1,
                Price = 5,
                PublisherId=3, 
                //Publisher = Publishers.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Name.Equals("Bard"))
            });
```